# Recode all but one value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to recode data on loan statuses so that every observation is either Default or Fully Paid. Specifically, I'd like to recode anyone != 'Fully Paid' as 'Default'.

Here are my values:

```
df.loan_status.unique()

array(['Fully Paid', 'Charged Off', 'Default', 'Late (31-120 days)',
   'In Grace Period', 'Late (16-30 days)',
   'Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Fully Paid',
   'Does not meet the credit policy. Status:Charged Off', 'Issued'], dtype=object)
```

I tried the following code but all observations got recoded as 'Default':

```
statuses= df['loan_status'].unique()
for status in statuses:
    if status!='Fully Paid':
        df['loan_status']='Default'
```

Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not setting the element corresponding to what you test. You need something like `df[df['loan_status']!='Fully Paid']='Default'`, or MaxU's suggestion below (I'm not closely familiar with pandas).

Comment: @AndrasDeak, i think this would be bit more robust: `df.loc[df['loan_status']!='Fully Paid', 'loan_status']='Default'`

Comment: @MaxU oh definitely, I'm only tangentially familiar with pandas. Hence "something like" ;) Thanks.

Comment: @MaxU there are probably dozens of duplicates for this question, I just didn't look. I generally try to keep in mind that the purpose of SO is to collect a knowledge base, and I don't post full answers to sufficiently simple questions. Furthermore, as I've noted, I'm not familiar enough with pandas anyway:) Feel free to post yours if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this approach.

***Andras Deak / MaxU; option 1***

```
df.loc[df.loan_status.ne('Fully Paid'), 'loan_status'] = 'Default'
```

***Option 2***
`pd.Series.where`

```
ls = df.loan_status
df.update(ls.where(ls.eq('Fully Paid'), 'Default'))
```

***Option 3***
`pd.Series.mask`

```
ls = df.loan_status
df.update(ls.mask(ls.ne('Fully Paid')).fillna('Default'))
```

***Option 4***
`numpy.where`

```
ls = df.loan_status.values
paid, dflt = 'Fully Paid', 'Default'
df.loc[:, 'loan_status'] = np.where(ls == paid, paid, dflt)
```